# Cannot update developer story

Tags: bug, developer-story

My profile is here - https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/61311

The story ends with Crawford And Co. I'm trying to add my current contract. When I click save the UI doesn't report any errors, and the request in the Network tab returns a 200 - but the item isn't added to my profile.

The body in the post is

> fkey=(omitted)&userId=61311&itemType=Job&Company=Xoserve+Limited&Title=C%23+Contractor&Url=https%3A%2F%2Fxoserve.com&LogoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FAM1pU.png&Tags=azure+blazor+fluxor+azureservicebus+azure-storage-blobs+entity-framework-core&DescriptionRaw=Developing+a+system+to+manage+a+nation-wide+gas%2Felectricity+supplier+switching+service.&StartDate-month=1&StartDate-year=2020&EndDate-month=&EndDate-year=&IsCurrent=on